# AngularJS : Error: $compile:tpload Error Loading Template

Tags: jquery, angularjs

The below **.js** is in **CG510_CLAIM_DB** package.

When trying to access .xhtml files from different package **CG510_CLAIM_Home**, file not found exception is coming.
Can anyone please help in fixing this issue.

```
var claimDBApp = angular.module('claimDBApp', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);
claimDBApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
  when('/AddNewOrder', {
    templateUrl: '../CG510_CLAIM_Home/html/add_order.xhtml',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  }).
  when('/ShowOrders', {
    templateUrl: '../CG510_CLAIM_Home/html/show_orders.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  }).
  otherwise({
      templateUrl: '../CG510_CLAIM_Home/html/show_orders.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Javascript has no native understanding of packages - I assume you just meant that your .js file is in the CG510_CLAIM_DB folder. You're getting a file not found exception, so obviously your file isn't being found. Have you tried switching up the templateUrl? Try './html/add_order.xhtml', for example.